# Which product operation should be used in affine transformation?

Tags: tensor, affine-transformations

Affine transformation as I am aware can be expressed as either *dot product* followed by addition or a *matrix multiplication* followed by addition

$$a.x+b$$
$$a^{T}x + b$$

where the first one is based on dot product and the second one is based on matrix multiplication. it should be noticed that $a, x$ are column vectors here and $b$ is a real number.

In case if a matrix $a$ is compatible (say order $m \times n$) and $x, b$ are column vectors of order $m \times 1$. Then affine transformation is (generally) a matrix multiplication followed by a vector addition.

$$a^{T}x + b$$

I think it is correct.

I have doubt about the product operation between $a$ and $b$ if $a, b$ and $x$ are tensors of higher dimensions. In the case of tensors, should we need to perform *Hadamard product* or normal matrix multiplication? Or are they both equivalent like in the case of affine transformation on column vectors?

I got this doubt because I encountered an affine transformation that neither uses dot product nor matrix multiplication but uses Hadamard product.

---

**Background**: Recently I came across an affine transformation that applies Hadamard product on reshaped weight $a$ and input $x$ and then adds reshaped bias $b$ to it

Initially, the dimensions are as follows

```
a -> [r, c]
x -> [r, c, d1, d2]
b -> [r, c]
```

Later they reshaped weight and bias to the shape of the input

```
a -> [r, c, d1, d2]
x -> [r, c, d1, d2]
b -> [r, c, d1, d2]
```

and finally, they are performing `a * x + b`

here $*$ is Hadamard product, an element-wise multiplication operation and (i think) is entirely different from normal matrix multiplication.

Is there any clue on what they did? Is it possible to view Hadamard's product as normal matrix multiplication?

Comment: please do comment in-case of any clarifications needed.